# python: import class from a different subfolder in the parent folder (tests)

Tags: python, unit-testing, visual-studio-code, dependencies

I moved my tests to a separate subfolder in the project, and now testing my classes does not work anymore.

```
|--  project
|   |main.py
|   |-- lib
|   |   |__init__.py
|   |   |myclass.py
|   |-- tests
|   |   |__init__.py
|   |   |test_myclass.py
```

Both **init** files are empty.

but when I run the test (i'm in the tests folder and typing `python -m unittest`) I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib'
```

at the line `from lib.myclass import Myclass`

I also saw that one could [use sys and os to add the parent folder to the path](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-import-from-parent-directory/), but each time that I do it, the code that adds it is automatically going under all the imports in vscode (I guess due to some automatic formatting?) and therefore is not ran on time.

Comment: do you have `if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()` in test file?

Comment: no, but now with @JohnyCapo 's hint its working. It was just me being in the wrong folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because once you are in tests folder your working directory `dir` is:

```
.\
.\test_mycalss.py
```

You should run tests from `project` so your working directory will cover whole tree:

```
.\
.\main.py
.\lib\
and so on
```

Your project cannot view `lib.myclass` because in folder **tests** there is no folder **lib**.